# NextJS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html-input

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to add the `type` attribute to `<input>` tag in NextJS in the following function.

```
const InputComponent = ({value, prefix, id, placeholder, autoCompleteLabel}: InputComponentProps) => {
    const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

    let ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

    const onClick = () => {
        setFocused(true);
    };
    const onBlur = () => {
        setFocused(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (focused)
            ref.current?.focus()
        else
            ref.current?.blur()
    }, [focused]);

    return (
        <div className="group flex flex-col border p-2 w-full focus-within:border-black border-gray-300 transition-all space-y-1" onClick={onClick}>
            <label htmlFor={id} className={"text-md"}>{value}</label>
            <div className={"flex flex-row"}>
                <span className={"text-gray-500"}>
                    {prefix}
                </span>
                <input ref={ref} onBlur={onBlur} type={"tel"} id={id} autoComplete={autoCompleteLabel ? autoCompleteLabel : "off"} name={id} pattern={"[0-9]{10}"} maxLength={10} placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : ""} className={"outline-none flex-grow " + ((prefix) ? "pl-2" : "")}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But as soon as I remove the attribute the error disappears. I hope someone can help me out with this.

The error/warning is different on each browser:

Chrome:

```
content.js:formatted:2942 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
    at Object.i [as checkAttributes] (content.js:formatted:2942)
    at content.js:formatted:3141
    at Object.y [as scanForm] (content.js:formatted:3143)
    at y (content.js:formatted:4292)
    at Object.validate (content.js:formatted:4235)
    at content.js:formatted:4266
```

Safari:
`no error or warning`

Firefox:

```
nvalid HMR message: {"action":"sync","hash":"a3c905b1d9bff16a","warnings":[],"errors":[]}
Error: No router instance found.
You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.
```

But there is no error on the server, it is a client side error and that's all the information I'm able to get from the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is caused due to a chrome extension...
And the HMR message is a bug in Next.JS which has been reported

Answer (score 1):

i guess because of, it treating it like json with key value pair,
`{"Key":"Value"}`
replace this,

```
<input type={"tel"} />
```

with this, this will work for sure,

```
<input type="tel" />
```

this issue is trickey one, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6713
here you can get worked solutions

Comment: Nope, does not work, already tried that :/

Comment: can you put your error stack trace please, is it becaz of `refs`

Comment: I updated the question with a few more details that will be helpful, but I'm not sure how to get a stack trace as there is no error on the server, just browser and the browser is only throwing that info back